Koin - using scopes in isloated context when building a library with koin
I am using koin in an SDK, i create an isolated koin context as explained in the docs,  however, i want to allow the SDK consumer to turn the SDK off, effectively clearing all classes created by the SDK, however, if i call stopKoin or close(), and u try to init the SDK again, it will crash with org.koin.core.error.ClosedScopeException: Scope '_' is closed
I assume i need to use scopes here but i find it hard to understand from the docs, how i can incorporate scopes into my structure.
I have an object called KoinInstance
object KoinInstance {
    
    val isGlobalKoinStarted: Boolean
        get() = try {
            GlobalContext.get() // Attempts to get the global Koin context
            true // If it succeeds, Koin has been started
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            false // If it fails, Koin has not been started
        }

    val koinApp = if (isGlobalKoinStarted) {
            koinApplication {
                modules(
                    listOf(listOfModules),
                )
            }
        } else {
            startKoin {
                modules(listOfModules)
            }
        }

    val koin = koinApp.koin
}

And i extend the KoinScopeComponent like this
interface MyKoinComponent : KoinComponent {

    // Override default Koin instance
    override fun getKoin(): Koin = KoinInstance.koin
}

I initilize koin like this:
KoinInstance.koinApp.androidContext(context.applicationContext)
This works well until i try to call close/unloadModules/stopKoin to remove my classes and init the KoinApp again.
Any idea how i can incorporate scopes into this approach?

After some help from the guys at the #koin channel in the kotlinlng slack, i relized i dont need to call startkoin at all and i can just call my isolated context
object KoinInstance {
    val koinApp = koinApplication {
        modules(
            listOf(
                appModule,
                databaseModule,
                networkModule,
                repositoryModule,
                coroutineModule,
                syncModule,
            ),
        )
    }

    val koin = koinApp.koin
}

This allows me to call stopKoin and clear my classes without worrying about it affecting the consumer app
